# Email form is messing up UTF-8 text

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I have a PHP form on my website. It collects text strings from HTML input elements, then sends the text to my mailbox. However, when people type in text in other languages, the email appears garbled. The text appears to be okay in the Web browser. There's even some JavaScript code that gets/sets some of these form fields, and seems to do so correctly.

Maybe the PHP code is not treating the text as unicode? Or the text gets sent to my mailbox using the wrong encoding? I would appreciate some help, thanks.

I have already added

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf8");
```

to the top of the PHP files.

Here is a part of the PHP form that gets the inputted values using POST.

```
$name       = $_POST["name"];
$email      = $_POST["email"];
$message    = $_POST["message"];
$titletxt   = $_POST["titletxt"];
$titleurl   = $_POST["titleurl"];
$legend     = $_POST["legend"];
$command    = $_POST["command"];
$binding    = $_POST["binding"];
$layout     = $_POST["layout"];
```

Here is a part of the PHP form that emails me the text:

```
    mail
    (
        "blahblah@blah.com",
        "VGKD Bindings Submission",
        "NAME:\t\t" . $name     . "\n" .
        "EMAIL:\t\t"    . $email    . "\n" .
        "MESSAGE:\t"    . $message  . "\n" .
        "GAME TITLE:\t" . $titletxt . "\n" .
        "GAME URL:\t"   . $titleurl . "\n" .
        "LAYOUT:\t\t"   . $layout   . "\n\n" .
        "LEGENDS:\n"    . $legend   . "\n\n" .
        "COMMANDS:\n"   . $command  . "\n\n" .
        "BINDINGS:\n"   . $binding  . "\n\n"
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try to add **utf-8** charset header to your mail function, for example

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

$headers .= 'From: <example@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: example@example.com' . "\r\n";

 mail
    (
        "blahblah@blah.com",
        "VGKD Bindings Submission",
        "NAME:\t\t" . $name     . "\n" .
        "EMAIL:\t\t"    . $email    . "\n" .
        "MESSAGE:\t"    . $message  . "\n" .
        "GAME TITLE:\t" . $titletxt . "\n" .
        "GAME URL:\t"   . $titleurl . "\n" .
        "LAYOUT:\t\t"   . $layout   . "\n\n" .
        "LEGENDS:\n"    . $legend   . "\n\n" .
        "COMMANDS:\n"   . $command  . "\n\n" .
        "BINDINGS:\n"   . $binding  . "\n\n",
        $headers
    );
```

The `header()` function sends a raw HTTP header to a client browser, but `mail` function with the variable `$headers` sends headers to email.

Comment: That worked thanks! One difference is I changed "text/html" in your example to "text\plain", since I need the text to be formatted in a certain way.